# Spring Boot `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, autowired

I am a Spring Boot newbie and I have a simple application which has a controller and a Thymeleaf template.

When the application starts, in order to see if everything is working, a Spring `ApplicationListener` called `RepoTester` should run to check the methods of a service class. The service class calls methods of the `PersonRepository` which simply extends Spring's `CrudRepository`. But every time I go to try running the application, it falls over giving me the message:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoTester': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private webapps.city2016.micro.code.service.PersonService webapps.city2016.micro.code.bootstrap.RepoTester.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private webapps.city2016.micro.code.repo.PersonRepository webapps.city2016.micro.code.service.PersonServiceImpl.personRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [webapps.city2016.micro.code.repo.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

But I cannot see why.

The `ApplicationListener` class is simply:

```
@Component
public class RepoTester implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RepoTester.class);   

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    logger.info(RepoTester.class.getName() + ".onApplicationEvent() method called."); 

    // Create Person.
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Cleo Markham");
    person.setAddress("48 Alysbury Road");
    person.setTelephone("34561287");
    person.setEmail("c.laithwaite@collosus.net");
    person = personService.save(person);
```

The `Person` class is simply:

```
public class Person {

    // Attributes.    
    private Integer personId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String telephone;
    private String email;
```

With `getter` and `setter` methods for each attribute.

The application also has a properties file called `application.properties` specifying the Derby database to use:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The code of the service class is simply:

```
@Service()
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersonServiceImpl.class);   

    public PersonServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Integer personId) {
        logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".delete() method called."); 

        personRepository.delete(personId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(Integer personId) {
        logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".exists() method called."); 

        return personRepository.exists(personId);
    }

    @Override
    public Person findOne(Integer personId) {
        logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".findOne() method called."); 

        return personRepository.findOne(personId);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Person> findAll() {
        logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".findAll() method called."); 

        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Person save(Person person) {
        logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".save() method called."); 

        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
```

And the repository is:

```
package webapps.city2016.micro.code.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import webapps.city2016.micro.code.model.Person;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

My Maven file is:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    webapps.city2016.micro
    RegistrationSpringBootThymeleaf1
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    
        UTF-8
        1.8
        1.8

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>                    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<name>RegistrationSpringBootThymeleaf1</name>
```

Can anyone advise where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of the answers posted but without success so the application has been converted over to Spring JDBC with a manually written DAO class and it works perfectly.

Any advice concerning JPA would be welcome though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate Person with JPA annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    // Attributes.    
    private Integer personId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String telephone;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getPersonId() { ... }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() { ... }
```

Comment: The same problem occurs unfortunately.

Comment: Did you annotate all of the getters? Did you also put the EnableJpaRepositories back to the Configuration file?

Comment: Even with the getters of the actual variables themselves annotated, the project still fails.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post it unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think I can help any further :(

Comment: Thanks for the help provided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the requirements here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data

Or check that you have done everything that's mentioned in this tutorial:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Particularly check that you have:

- Main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`
- Entity class annotated with `@Entity`
- The primary key on the entity annotated with `@Id` and that the type matches the generics type of your Repository (Integer).
- Your entity and repository classes are at the package level of the main class or below.

Comment: Main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`: Yes. Entity class annotated with `@Entity`: Yes. The primary key...: Yes. Your entity and repository classes: Yes.And the wretched application still fails!